# $3\sigma$ region of locally non-parabolic cost function

Tags: normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, covariance-matrix, fisher-information

Consider you have an optimization problem where your are given:

- Dataset $(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})$
- $\mathbf{x}$ is perfectly known
- $\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{y}_{\text{true}} + \mathbf{n}$   with $n_i \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0,\sigma^2\right) $
- Variance $\sigma^2$ is known and noise is IID
- $\mathbf{y}$ depends nonlinearly on parameters $\mathbf{\beta}$

Given that you find the parameters $\mathbf{\beta}_{opt}$ that are:
$$\mathbf{\beta}_{opt} =  \underset{\mathbf{\beta}}{\text{arg min}} \,\, -\text{log}(\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{\beta}; y))$$
with $\mathcal{L}$ being the likelihood, i.e. in this case the problem denotes the least-square fit under the weight given by the variance $\sigma^2$.
For this $\mathbf{\beta}_{opt}$ you evaluate the, here positive definite, Hessian:
$$H(\mathbf{\beta}_{opt},\sigma^2)>0$$
The covariance of the estimate $\mathbf{\beta}_{opt}$ is given by the inverse of the Hessian
$$\text{cov}(\mathbf{\beta}_{opt}) = H^{-1}(\mathbf{\beta}_{opt},\sigma^2)$$
This is adequate under the *assumption* that the cost function can locally be described by a parabola.

I could draw samples from the distribution $$\beta_\text{s}\sim\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{\beta}_{opt},\text{cov}(\mathbf{\beta}_{opt}))$$

**My Question**: Given drawn samples from $\beta_\text{s}\sim\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{\beta}_{opt},\text{cov}(\mathbf{\beta}_{opt}))$, and compute the cost function values of $-\text{log}(\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{\beta}_s; y))$, can I make a statement about the "parabolicity" of the cost function around that value? I mean in terms of e.g. a threshold that tells me whether the cost function increases too fast or too slow. I would like to reject samples that go above a threshold that would denote the $3\sigma$ region of the ellipse given by $H^{-1}(\mathbf{\beta}_{opt},\sigma^2)$.